# C# Drawing Libraries

Tags: c#, xml, graph, drawing, cyclic

I'm looking for a library which will enable me to visualize some xml entities I have, and manipulate them graphically (something similar to a UML design package, but simpler), like a cyclic flow graph.

Anybody have any ideas where I should start? Preferrably I would like something managed, but if it's easier to do a HTML+JS implementation or something that would be reasonable.

Basic requirements:
- Visualizally draw a representation of a C#/XML class.
- Allow to select it
- Draw lines between two entities.
- Perform operations would could remove/move or place it before another item in the graph.

Any help/direction you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Of those looked at, Microsoft GLEE definitely looks to be in the general direction of what I want. Easy to use, and auto-layouts, just need to configure it to business logic and it's done.